# Filling markers when plotting in a loop

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to plot 31 different vectors in a single figure in MATLAB. I am using a circular marker 'o', for plotting every vector and I want to have every vector painted in a different color and also I want to fill the markers as well with the **same** color as the markers edges.

I am using the following code:

```
while (n<=31)
   plot(x(n),y(n),'o',rand(1,3))  % Not filled markers
   n=n+1;
end
```

The problem is that since I am using a random for the color selection, when I try to run the following code:

```
while (n<=31)
   plot(x(n),y(n),'o','MarkerFaceColor',rand(1,3))  % Filled markers
   n=n+1;
end
```

The marker edge and the marker filling have different colors. I don't know how to fix this, maybe I shouldn't use the random for selecting the color but I don't know how to fix it, to obtain the same color in the marker edge and in the filling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using [`scatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html) for this rather than creating `n` different plot objects that you then have to manage. Using the [`CData` property](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter.html#input_argument_c) it is possible to set a separate color for each of your data points.

```
colors = rand(31, 3);

x = rand(31,1);
y = rand(31,1);

s = scatter(x, y, 'filled', 'CData', colors);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your alternative works really good as well.

Answer (score 3):

'MarkerEdgeColor' is the property you want, in addition to FaceColor

```
while (n<=31)
   c = rand(1,3);
   plot(x(n),y(n),'o','MarkerFaceColor', c, 'MarkerEdgeColor', c);
   n=n+1;
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Just as a matter of curiosity, is there any other way to use different colors than using the random command?

Comment: @Airman01 use a colormap? like `clr = hsv(N)` then `c = clr(i,:)`

Comment: Thank you very much @Amro, I like better the combination of colors that is obtained with the "hsv" function.

Comment: @Airman01 be sure to check out my answer below for an alternate approach

Comment: @Suever and Amro are correct.  scatter is a much better solution.  Consider moving your accept to that answer.